# python installing package with submodules

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging, python-install

I have a custom project package with structure like:

```
 package-dir/
     mypackage/
         __init__.py
         submodule1/
              __init__.py
              testmodule.py
         main.py
     requirements.txt
     setup.py
```

using `cd package-dir` followed by `$pip install -e .` or `pip install .` as suggested by [python-packaging](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html?highlight=pip%20install) as long as I access the package from `package-dir`

For example :

```
 $cd project-dir
 $pip install .
```

at this point this works:

```
 $python -c 'import mypackage; import submodule1'
```

but This does not work

```
 $ cd some-other-dir
 $ python -c 'import mypackage; import submodule1'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named submodule1
```

How to install all the submodules?

also, if i check the `package-dir/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mypackage` dir, I only see the immediate files in `mypackage/*.py` and NO `mypackage/submodule1`

`setup.py` looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup
from pip.req import parse_requirements

reqs = parse_requirements('./requirements.txt', session=False)
install_requires = [str(ir.req) for ir in reqs]


def readme():
    with open('README.rst') as f:
        return f.read()

setup(name='mypackage',
      version='1.6.1',
      description='mypackage',
      long_description=readme(),
      classifiers=[

      ],
      keywords='',
      url='',
      author='',
      author_email='',
      license='Proprietary',
      packages=['mypackage'],
      package_dir={'mypackage': 'mypackage'},
      install_requires=install_requires,
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False,
      test_suite='nose.collector',
      tests_require=['nose'],
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': ['mypackage=mypackage.run:run'],
      }
      )
```

Comment: does `python -c 'from mypackage import submodule1'` work in some-other-dir?

Comment: no only in same `package-dir`, update some more info at the end about build, if that helps

Comment: What's the content of `setup.py`? Specifically, do you have a line like `packages=setuptools.find_packages()`?

Comment: @NilsWerner update, and No I do not have that line .. will try that

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`setup.py` is missing information about your package structure. You can enable auto-discovery by adding a line

```
setup(
    # ...
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

to it.

Comment: I think find_packages() works because the submodule as shown has a `__init__.py` file.  What happens when the submodule is actually the top-level directory with a setup.py file but no init.py, and the code is a directory below?

Comment: Please open a new question.