# Submodule import not working on Google Colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I have a package called `boo` which I install on google colab from a github repository. The installation process looks fine and results in success message `Successfully installed boo-0.1`. However `import boo` fails on first internal import.

I replicated the same installation steps in a local virtual environment and package worked, but not on collab.

Here are my steps and error trace:

```
!rm -rf sandbox
!git clone https://github.com/ru-corporate/sandbox.git
!pip install -r sandbox/requirements.txt 
!pip install sandbox/.
```

Alternatively, I tried

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/ru-corporate/sandbox.git@master
```

The error trace is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-fc0b1d036b35> in <module>()
----> 1 import boo

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/boo/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from boo.boo import download, build, read_dataframe, files
      2 from boo.views.whatis import whatis

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/boo/boo.py in <module>()
      3 from tqdm import tqdm
      4 
----> 5 from boo.file.download import curl
```

Basically, from root `__init__.py` the import goes to root `boo.py` and stumbles upon finding `boo/file/download.py`.

How do I make this package work on collab?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the subpackage behavior by editing `setup.py` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45087985/1758363):

```
  # ...
  packages=setuptools.find_packages()
  # ...
```

Somehow Colab is more restrictive on this parameter than local installation.